# How to start and stop another node process in electron in Windows?

Tags: node.js, electron

I want to start another node process from my electron app. I also want to kill/stop that process. How can I do it in electron ?

Comment: Do you want to run a nodejs file or run another electron app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via NodeJs in the main process ([Child Process Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)) if you want a node process.

If you want to add new Windows you can do so by defining BrowserWindow objects `const myNewWindow = new BrowserWindow();` from the main process, you can kill those windows via the `close` or `destroy` method on the object like `myNewWindow.close()`